# Excel formula which merges rows that have consecutive end and starting dates and checks if national holidays are included

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel task which beyond my skills. I've been experimenting with Chat GPT but so far it has only given my invalid functions as result. Any help would be appreciated and I hope this proves that a human brain still beats AI when it comes to solving tasks like this.

I have a table structured as it shows:
[image: table1]

The table is a list of staff vacation days. My task is to find if a person has a midweek holiday included within his or hers vacation period which would result an extra holiday for the person. The extra holiday is only given, if there's at least 1 vacation day before the midweek holiday and 2 after, or 2 days before and 1 after.

What makes the task a bit challenging is the way the data has been gathered. One UserId might have multiple vacations spread on separate rows so the formula should first merge the duplicates in column A together before checking if the conditions are met.

The data is gathered monthly. Since there are usually only a small number of midweek holidays in a month one option would be to manually type the specific midweek holiday dates into column D.

I've tried to use SUMPRODUCT- and WORKDAY-functions but so far with poor results.

Sample data from Dec 2021:

| User_ID | Start_date | End_date | Holiday |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A401435 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 | 6.12.2021 |  |
| A401477 | 27.12.2021 | 28.12.2021 | 24.12.2021 |  |
| A401477 | 29.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 | 25.12.2021 |  |
| A403713 | 27.12.2021 | 28.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |
| A403976 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A405378 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410024 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410026 | 29.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410077 | 1.12.2021 | 1.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410077 | 2.12.2021 | 3.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410077 | 7.12.2021 | 10.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410077 | 20.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410077 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410097 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410112 | 27.12.2021 | 28.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410112 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410134 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410173 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410177 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410177 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410181 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410191 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410191 | 28.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410194 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410269 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410269 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410279 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410286 | 27.12.2021 | 27.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410286 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410322 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410365 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410380 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410388 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410388 | 27.12.2021 | 29.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410388 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410392 | 7.12.2021 | 7.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410392 | 16.12.2021 | 17.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410392 | 20.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410392 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410396 | 16.12.2021 | 17.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410396 | 20.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410396 | 27.12.2021 | 30.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410427 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410437 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410437 | 27.12.2021 | 29.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410438 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410440 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410473 | 29.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410486 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410505 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A410511 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487241 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487245 | 21.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487245 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487249 | 10.12.2021 | 10.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487249 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487264 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487275 | 27.12.2021 | 27.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487277 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487283 | 3.12.2021 | 3.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487290 | 13.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487291 | 1.12.2021 | 1.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487291 | 21.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| A487291 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| aas567 | 22.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| aas567 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| aav168 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| abx385 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| aca073 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| acf293 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| acf293 | 27.12.2021 | 30.12.2021 |  |  |
| aci903 | 20.12.2021 | 22.12.2021 |  |  |
| aci903 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| ada403 | 20.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| ade548 | 23.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| aei402 | 21.12.2021 | 22.12.2021 |  |  |
| aei402 | 28.12.2021 | 28.12.2021 |  |  |
| aet143 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| agj746 | 20.12.2021 | 20.12.2021 |  |  |
| agj746 | 21.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| ahh757 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| ahi565 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| ahi565 | 27.12.2021 | 27.12.2021 |  |  |
| ahm200 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| ahm200 | 29.12.2021 | 29.12.2021 |  |  |
| aid853 | 7.12.2021 | 10.12.2021 |  |  |
| aiw345 | 20.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| aiw345 | 27.12.2021 | 28.12.2021 |  |  |
| aiy586 | 28.12.2021 | 29.12.2021 |  |  |
| akh211 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| akn993 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| ako251 | 27.12.2021 | 28.12.2021 |  |  |
| alv173 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| alx740 | 3.12.2021 | 3.12.2021 |  |  |
| alz616 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| ama586 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| anb243 | 21.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| anb243 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| anf568 | 1.12.2021 | 2.12.2021 |  |  |
| apq605 | 27.12.2021 | 28.12.2021 |  |  |
| apx029 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| atk007 | 22.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| atk007 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| atm461 | 29.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| ato110 | 20.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| ato110 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| aty537 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| aut718 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| avd323 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| avd323 | 27.12.2021 | 30.12.2021 |  |  |
| avf866 | 20.12.2021 | 21.12.2021 |  |  |
| awt260 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| axd416 | 20.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| axd416 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| axz933 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| ayz479 | 29.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| azk648 | 27.12.2021 | 29.12.2021 |  |  |
| azn190 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| azn190 | 27.12.2021 | 27.12.2021 |  |  |
| azn190 | 29.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| azu294 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| azx033 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| bab370 | 28.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| baf251 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| bap030 | 21.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| bap030 | 30.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| bbw675 | 15.12.2021 | 16.12.2021 |  |  |
| bbw675 | 20.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| bcv032 | 2.12.2021 | 3.12.2021 |  |  |
| bds169 | 28.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| bea467 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| bea467 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| beh274 | 28.12.2021 | 28.12.2021 |  |  |
| beh274 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| beh841 | 20.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| beh841 | 27.12.2021 | 27.12.2021 |  |  |
| beu363 | 2.12.2021 | 3.12.2021 |  |  |
| beu363 | 7.12.2021 | 7.12.2021 |  |  |
| bfo649 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| bfo649 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| bgn419 | 3.12.2021 | 3.12.2021 |  |  |
| bhf801 | 21.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| bhf801 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| bhl636 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |
| bhl636 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| big613 | 20.12.2021 | 21.12.2021 |  |  |
| bjs688 | 27.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| blz401 | 31.12.2021 | 31.12.2021 |  |  |
| blz715 | 23.12.2021 | 23.12.2021 |  |  |

Comment: If you provide some relevant data then people will test, but an image puts us off...

Comment: You should add easy data to copy/paste and try stuff. Also, always add **expected output** How would you manually  calculate?

Comment: Have you applied the methods shown in my answer?

Comment: @SolarMike Took me a second to follow the logic behind your method, but it's simple and seems like it could work. But how about the issue, that the data is not intact and can be scattered on multiply rows? For example when the vacation is separated on many rows then each row would behave as an individual mini vacation thus not filling the conditions, and only when merged together the conditions would be met.

Comment: @Lekazard As I said, you should add expected output, specially when dealing with multiple rows. About *how about the issue, that the data is not intact and can be scattered on multiply rows?* probably you'll need VBA to merge data properly and study the data.

Answer (score 1):

So, quick and dirty using booleans, then AND() and finally IF() with AND(), but you can improve it:

[image]

You will probably need to consider doing >= instead of just >, same for <=.

Comment: Multiplying booleans is very dirty indeed, why don't you `AND` them? Using a simple `IF` you can turn the `TRUE` into `1` and vice versa afterwards.

Comment: @Dominique I was bored of typing having to provide the data... But also the booleans was minimalist and works.